# JasperServer content viewing throws index out of bound exception

Tags: jasperserver

We are trying to access the content of Jasperserver using below URL.

http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/fileview/fileview/

When we try to hit this URL, we are getting below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.control.ContentRepositoryFileView.renderMergedOutputModel(ContentRepositoryFileView.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1001)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
```

Can anyone help us why we are getting this error? We have reports configured in the server and we are not sure why we are getting this error .

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify right URL to the specific content resource, for example:

http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/fileview/fileview/public/SomeReport.pdf

where `/public/SomeReport.pdf` is a path to the content resource. The content resource can be any of pdf, txt, xml, csv, etc but not any of JapserServer resources like reports, adhoc views, domains and etc.